# Convert 2 objects to an Array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, object

I have a query. I'm looking at Javascript in React Native and I have the output of a variable in this form, **Code N1** but I want the output of the variable to be ***Code N2***, I don't know how to convert two objects that are the ***console.log*** of my variable in an Array of objects. Thank you very much in advance.

---

Code N 1

---

```
Object {
  "city": "",
  "year": "",
}
Object {
  "city": "",
  "year": "",
}
```

---

Code N 2

---

```
Array [
  Object {
    "city": "",
    "year": "",
  },
  Object {
    "hour": "",
    "year": "",
  },
]
```

Comment: Array.push may be helpful here. const arr = []; arr.push({})

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried.

Comment: A single variable can not hold two objects like "Code N 1". You are probably logging the variable twice. you can make an array out of two objects like this `[obj1,obj2]`.

Comment: Hello Емил Цоков, I tried the code and it returns this. It's not what I wanted 
***Array [
  Objeto {
    "misdatos": Objeto {
      "ciudad": "",
      "año": ""
    },
  },
]
matriz [
  Objeto {
    "misdatos": Objeto {
      "ciudad": ""
      "año": ""
    },
  },
]***

Comment: True, you wrote wrong. Rakibul Islam Rafi. My variable returns 2 objects from Firebase because in the limit I put 2 but it can be the number I want but my idea is to pass it to an array. Array [ Object {} Object {]]

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried.

Comment: I'm on ReactNative and pass from Firebase to a component like this 

<ScrollView horizontal>
      {report.map((data, index) => (
        <Carrousel mydata={data} />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>


which when doing console.log() to mydata returns this:

Object {
  "city": "",     
  "year": ",
}
Object {
  "city": "",
  "year": "",
}


but to use it in the Carrousel I need something to this

Array [
  Object {
    "city": "",
    "year": "",
  },
  Object {
    "city": "",
    "year": "",
  },
 
]

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
function abc(){
var z = []

 var abc= {
  "city": "",
  "year": "",
}
 var def=  {
  "city": "",
  "year": "",
}
 z.push(abc);
 z.push(def);
  console.log(z);
}

abc();
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all when I have your level I also dedicate my time to respond to the new generations. I already resolved it. As I told you, I was passing data from one component to another and it was passed through a .map, so the Firebase records were passed in a props, but there I was making the mistake, I solved it by not using the .map to pass it, and then in the component that received the props just towards the .map. total thanks. Component 01 ***return (
         <Carrousel mydata={report} />
  );***